# How to find and install CIM Studio in Windows 7 and above?

Tags: windows, wmi

I very much want to find a download of CIM Studio.

If one Googles enough, one discovers that CIM Studio is now part of the WMI Administrative Tools and one finds a link identical or similar to:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=6430F853-1120-48DB-8CC5-F2ABDC3ED314

<strike>If one follows that link, one is redirected to a politely apologetic page explaining that the requested page is now gone and offers a Bing search using the appropriate keywords. The VERY FIRST link offered by Bing is the identical Microsoft link which fails.</strike>

EDIT: The above link now works properly again, but successfully running CIM Studio on Windows 7+ is not straight-forward.

Anyone know how to properly install CIM Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft links seems to be broken, but you can use the CNET Download.com site [`WMI Administrative Tools`](http://download.cnet.com/WMI-Administrative-Tools/3000-2383_4-75452613.html)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why Google didn't turn up any alternate downloads. I was half convinced MS had disallowed 3rd party sharing.

Answer (score 9):

Since it took me a bit to learn these nuances of getting WMI CIM Studio to run under Windows 7 or Windows 8 and IE11 (IE9 or later), I thought I'd share it here...

1. Install CIM Studio ([WMI Administrative Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24045), as indicated in @knb's answer)
2. Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` into the `<HEAD>` section ahead of SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBS" in the C:\Program Files (x86)\WMI Tools\studio.htm file. This override is necessary because CIM Studio uses VBScript code and IE11+ has dropped support for that.
3. Create a shortcut to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WMI Tools\studio.htm"
4. Configure the shortcut to run as Admin (Properties -> Advanced...)

Another option is to use [Microsoft WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) instead.

Comment: Can confirm the above answer still is valid in Win10.  The WMI Code Creator a sweet utility!

Answer (score 1):

These days, the WMITools.exe file can be retrieved directly from Microsoft again, at

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24045

It can be found easily with a simple google search  for "cim studio".

Comment: As of today, 31 May 2017, all of the links cited above are dead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all download reasources from Microsoft are going to disappear.

A good open-source alternative for CIM Studio is WMI Explorer which you can download from here: https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18051272)

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, would be difficult to "include the essential parts of the answer here" - as it would a big amount of source code.